# Why does Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 say there a tons of updates even after having updated while installing?

Tags: system-installation

The installer supposedly updated all packages when I told it to, but after restarting and running `$ sudo apt update` just to make sure, there are like 111 upgradable packages. I also saw today that Ubuntu Software Center reported no new updates, but `$ sudo apt update` did.

Comment: Unable to duplicate with the information given: I tested update-during-clean-install a week ago, and had no additional packages to upgrade after the first boot. It's one of my regular QA checks when updating cloud images.

Comment: Strange. Do you know of anything that a typical non-techie could've done 'wrong' during the process? The only change I made before installing was running `$ xrandr -o normal` because the display always starts sideways on my tablet (but I have the screen rotation locked now so it's not a nuisance). I also tried resizing an existing LVM partition which didn't work so I just let Ubuntu wipe the whole disk. Connected fine to my wifi (as far as I know. White wifi 'bars' icon became visible), chose minimal installation.

Comment: Made another edit.